# Spotlight no longer finds movies

Tags: finder, video, spotlight

Command-space for Spotlight search used to find video files in my ~/Movies folder (and elsewhere on my Mac). But since upgrading to Ventura, it no longer finds any MP4, MKV, MPG, or MOV files anywhere.

It finds folders and SRT files in the Movies folder (and elsewhere). It finds something new called “Photos from Apps”, which I wish I could disable. It offers to search the web, which I wish I could disable.

Here’s an example screenshot:
[image]

Here are my System Prefs:

[image]

MacOS Ventura 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: What happens if you search in Finder? In particular for "name .mov" and "kind movie".  This is to establish whether your problem is that the spotlight index is bad.

Comment: If I open a Finder window, hit command-f, type `.mov`, and select “file name contains .mov” in my home folder, I get a large list of found results. If I change the “kind” to “movie”, the results do not change.

Comment: So we know your spotlight index is good. I use Finder when I want to look for specific file types (like all .mov files). Much simpler than command-space Spotlight which tries to be over-helpful unless you have precise query.

Comment: Pressing command-space and typing the title of my desired movie worked for years, until Ventura. And it by far was the quickest method. Searching Finder instead requires many more keystrokes and trackpad swipes, and its results aren’t ordered by relevance (it would be quicker to switch to Finder, navigate to the Home folder, and navigate to the desired movie from there).